# How to disable DTD fetching using JAXB2.0

Tags: java, validation, jaxb, dtd

I'm trying to use JAXB to unmashall some XML which I used xjc to create in the first place. I don't want to do any validation on the unmarshalling, but even though I have disabled the validation according to the JAXB documentation with `u.setSchema(null);`, but this hasn't prevented a `FileNotFoundException` being thrown when it tries to run and can't find the schema.

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("blast");
Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
u.setSchema(null);
return u.unmarshal(blast)
```

I've seen similar questions for disabling SAX parsing from validation by setting the apache property `http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema` to `false`, but I can't get the Unmarshaller to use my own sax parser.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Below is sample code that demonstrates how to get a [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation to use your SAX parser:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXSource;

import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);

        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        spf.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
        XMLReader xmlReader = spf.newSAXParser().getXMLReader();
        InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new FileReader("input.xml"));
        SAXSource source = new SAXSource(xmlReader, inputSource);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Foo foo = (Foo) unmarshaller.unmarshal(source);
        System.out.println(foo.getValue());
    }

}
```

Comment: That didn't work for me but these did:  parser.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
    parser.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", false);

Comment: [This](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_(XXE)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#SAXTransformerFactory) website explains how it can be blocked on any of the major Java frameworks.

Comment: Seems that FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING is about entityExpansionLimit. Check the last part of the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/xml/jaxp/JAXP-Compatibility_150.html#JAXP_security

Comment: This answers the question "how do I get the Unmarshaller to use my own sax parser", but does not answer the question "How to disable DTD fetching using JAXB2.0".

Answer (score 21):

Building on the answers from @blaise-doughan and @aerobiotic, here is a solution that worked for me:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXSource;

import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

public class Demo2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyBean.class);

        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        spf.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
        spf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", false);

        XMLReader xmlReader = spf.newSAXParser().getXMLReader();
        InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(
                new FileReader("myfile.xml"));
        SAXSource source = new SAXSource(xmlReader, inputSource);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        MyBean foo = (MyBean) unmarshaller.unmarshal(source);
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me.Also additionally added `spf.setValidating(false);`  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In answer to the question "How to disable DTD fetching using JAXB2.0".

@sameer-puri links to https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/XML_External_Entity_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#SAXTransformerFactory which answers the question as follows:

> JAXB Unmarshaller
>
> Since a javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller parses XML and does not support any flags for disabling XXE, it's imperative to parse the untrusted XML through a configurable secure parser first, generate a source object as a result, and pass the source object to the Unmarshaller. For example:

```
//Disable XXE
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
spf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);
spf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", false);
spf.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);

//Do unmarshall operation
Source xmlSource = new SAXSource(spf.newSAXParser().getXMLReader(),
                                new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Object.class);
Unmarshaller um = jc.createUnmarshaller();
um.unmarshal(xmlSource);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the Unmarshaller directly from a javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXSource.

See the example on this page: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html

Than you "only" need to provide your own URIResolver to that SAXSource

Answer (score 0):

The above suggestions Nothing worked out for me...
Im suggesting this code which worked for me☺️
To remove Dtd from xml  ...Used regex
String str = event.getData();
str= str.replaceAll("<!DOCTYPE[^<>]*(?:<![^<>]*>[^<>]*)*>","");

Answer (score 0):

The `SAXParserFactory` solutions from @doughan and @Renaud didn't work for me. Due to error

> External DTD: Failed to read external DTD 'cXML.dtd', because 'http' access is not allowed due to restriction set by the accessExternalDTD property.

If you are behind a corporate proxy , the following solution works. It is based on `XMLInputFactory`

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import org.junit.Assert;

public class Demo3 {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(CXMLResponse.class);

    XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
    xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.SUPPORT_DTD, false);
    XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader("input.xml"));

    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    CXMLResponse parsedResponse = (CXMLResponse) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr);

    System.out.println(parsedResponse.toString());
  }
}
```

Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/13069681/311420 . Thanks again @bdoughan