# Ignoring DTDs when unmarshalling with EclipseLink MOXy

Tags: java, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy, spring-oxm

When trying to unmarshall some XML into a POJO using EclipseLink MOXy I'm getting a `FileNotFoundException` where it's looking for the document's DTD as a relative path.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.oxm.UnmarshallingFailureException: JAXB unmarshalling exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\deejay\Documents\workspace-sts-3.0.0.RELEASE\moxy-test\ieee_idams_exchange.dtd (The system cannot find the file specified)]
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.convertJaxbException(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:761)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:682)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:665)
    at com.mendeley.services.utility.EclipseLinkMarshaller.load(EclipseLinkMarshaller.java:29)
    at com.mendeley.MoxyTest.main(MoxyTest.java:31)
```

I'm providing "externalized metadata" as per [this example](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/Spring/JAXBMetadata), so I've no idea why it even needs a DTD. If I could get it to ignore the DTD, or not try and resolve it, that'd be great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could unmarshal from an `XMLStreamReader` that has DTD support disabled:

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.stream.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);

        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.SUPPORT_DTD, false);
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new StreamSource("input.xml"));

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Customer customer = (Customer) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr);
    }

}
```

**Extra**

If you want to write the DTD declaration you could do the following:

```
    XMLOutputFactory xof = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();
    XMLStreamWriter xsw = xof.createXMLStreamWriter(System.out);
    xsw.writeDTD("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">");

    Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
    marshaller.marshal(html, xsw);
    xsw.close();
```