# org.springframework.oxm.UnmarshallingFailureException: NPE while unmarshalling. Using spring resttemplate and jaxb

Tags: xml, rest, unmarshalling, resttemplate, jaxb2

I am trying to unmarshall the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<InfoResult>
    <resultCode>OK</resultCode>
    <msisdn>263771222608</msisdn>
    <make>Samsung</make>
    <model>Galaxy Grand Neo Plus I9060I</model>
    <settings>
        <setting>Internet</setting>
        <setting>Internet &amp; MMS</setting>
        <setting>MMS</setting>
        <setting>WAP</setting>
    </settings>
</InfoResult>
```

with header

```
Content-Type →application/vnd.mobilethink.setting-v1+xml
```

Problem if first of all restTemplate interprets as json so i tried to force content handler using code found here:
[Ignoring DTDs when unmarshalling with EclipseLink MOXy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13068791/ignoring-dtds-when-unmarshalling-with-eclipselink-moxy)

but i am getting mashalling error. So i drilled down to mashalling and done it manually:

```
private Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller=new Jaxb2Marshaller();

public Object unmarshal(String xmlString) {
    return marshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));
}

public InfoResult getSettingsInfo(String msisdn) {
    MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    headers.add("Accept", "application/vnd.mobilethink.setting-v1+xml");
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> infoResultResponseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(INFO_REQUEST_URL, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class, msisdn);
    String data = infoResultResponseEntity.getBody();
    Object o = unmarshal(data);
    return new InfoResult();
}
```

but i am still getting a mashalling exeption:

```
org.springframework.oxm.UnmarshallingFailureException: NPE while unmarshalling. This can happen on JDK 1.6 due to the presence of DTD declarations, which are disabled.; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:777)
        at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:753)
```

**Please help point out the bad code here.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got similar problem recently.

From the posted code it looks like `Jaxb2Marshaller` wasn't initialized correctly. It is necessary to set the `contextPath` or the `classesToBeBound` property which is mentioned in [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/oxm/jaxb/Jaxb2Marshaller.html).

Example correct code to initialize:

```
Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(RootEntity.class);
marshaller.afterPropertiesSet();
```

Comment: I had to go back to the branch to test that and it worked.

Wish i had this before the deadline!