# Prevent parsing XML files containing DTD using Jaxb2Marshaller

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb

I saw many solutions using XMLInputFactory, SAXParser and DocumentBuilderFactory. Our project is spring web service and the only thing we do is:

```
@Bean
public Jaxb2Marshaller unmarshaller() {
   Jaxb2Marshaller unmarshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
   unmarshaller.setContextPath("foo");
   unmarshaller.setProcessExternalEntities(false);
   return unmarshaller;
}
```

And then we pass this marshaller and unmarshaller to MarshallingPayloadMethodProcessor. So my question is if there is some property for Jaxb2Marshaller that will prevent DTD. Something like: `unmarshaller.setProperty(foo.SUPPORT_DTD, false);`

We have .xsd schema but in case of [xml bomb](http://www.soapui.org/Security/xml-bomb.html) the entity needs to be exanded for purpose of validation, so it seems like this is not the solution.

Comment: Answered partially here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909465/how-to-disable-dtd-fetching-using-jaxb2-0

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see from the code, this must be the default behaviour.

In the JAXB RI there is a context property [`com.sun.xml.bind.disableXmlSecurity`](https://github.com/gf-metro/jaxb/blob/master/jaxb-ri/runtime/impl/src/main/java/com/sun/xml/bind/api/JAXBRIContext.java#L551) which is [reasonably set to `false`](https://github.com/gf-metro/jaxb/blob/master/jaxb-ri/runtime/impl/src/main/java/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/ContextFactory.java#L95-L97) by default. JAXB RI the uses this property when it [creates the parser](https://github.com/gf-metro/jaxb/blob/master/jaxb-ri/runtime/impl/src/main/java/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/runtime/unmarshaller/UnmarshallerImpl.java#L154). So, at the end it [configures](https://github.com/gf-metro/jaxb/blob/master/jaxb-ri/core/src/main/java/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/util/XmlFactory.java#L128) the [`FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/XMLConstants.html#FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING) feature of the parser:

```
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        if (LOGGER.isLoggable(Level.FINE)) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.FINE, "SAXParserFactory instance: {0}", factory);
        }
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        factory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, !isXMLSecurityDisabled(disableSecureProcessing));
        return factory;
```

You can also use the system property [`javax.xml.accessExternalDTD`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/properties/properties.html).

See also this answer:

> [How to disable DTD fetching using JAXB2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909465/how-to-disable-dtd-fetching-using-jaxb2-0)

If you want to make it ever more secure, you may write and configure your own [entity resolver](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/EntityResolver.html).