# How to Disable DTD fetching using JAXB 2.0 with string input

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have the following code (works OK) and I must secure it adding some restrictions to the unmarshaling process

```
public static Response getObjectBinResponse1(String xml) throws JAXBException{
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Response.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
    Response rsp=(Response) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader); 
    reader.close();
    return rsp;
}
```

I tried this:

```
public static Response getObjectBinResponse2(String xml) throws JAXBException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, UnsupportedEncodingException{
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Response.class);

    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    spf.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
    spf.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
    spf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", false);


    XMLReader xmlReader = spf.newSAXParser().getXMLReader();


    InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
    SAXSource source = new SAXSource(xmlReader, inputSource);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    Response rsp=(Response) unmarshaller.unmarshal(source); 

    return rsp;
}
```

But this code raises the following error:

```
    javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"ns0:Response"). Expected elements are <{http://www.xxx.yy/aaa/vbb/v1}Response>
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:726)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:247)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:242)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:109)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1131)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:556)
```

I tried the code of this answer by changing a source file to a string.
[How to disable DTD fetching using JAXB2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909465/how-to-disable-dtd-fetching-using-jaxb2-0)

The name of class is correct

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Response")
public class Response {
```

I have the file package-info.java correct

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.xxx.yy/aaa/vbb/v1")
package my.generated.package.from.xsd.with.jaxb;
```

And the xml string looks like

```
String xml="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><ns0:Response xmlns:ns0=\"http://www.xxx.yy/aaa/vbb/v1\"><enca......
```

If I change this line

```
SAXSource source = new SAXSource(xmlReader, inputSource);
```

To this

```
SAXSource source = new SAXSource(inputSource);
```

Works, but I need the xmlReader because of restrictions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, after SAXParserFactory it is necessary to place setNamespaceAware=true

```
    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    spf.setNamespaceAware(true);
```